# AJAX Form submission with CRUD

Tags: python, ajax, model-view-controller, web2py

Is it possible to validate CRUD form fields using ajax without submitting the form in web2py?

I have gone through the web2py online doc and have seen this link:
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11#Ajax-form-submission
So we may do it using custom html. 
But I want to do it using CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use custom HTML for Crud forms, but by default, Crud will insert hidden `_formname` and `_formkey` fields in the form (the latter is used to protect against CSRF attacks). Because Crud will expect those fields to be submitted with the form, the form has to be created via Crud, and the form object has to be passed to the view so you can include those fields. See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#Custom-forms) for details on creating custom HTML for forms.

Note, to make it easier to submit the form via Ajax, you might consider putting the form in an Ajax component via `LOAD()` (see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12#Components)).

Comment: But I do not want to get it done using custom HTML.**I want to use CRUD forms for client side validation**. Or even SQLFORM will do. Is no time saving client side validator available?

Comment: Sorry, your question was not clear. You said you wanted to validate using Ajax (which involves server communication), not solely on the client (which doesn't involve Ajax). The example from the book you pointed out doesn't do client-side validation either. The short answer is no, the web2py validators do not run on the client side -- all validators are server-side only. The only client-side validation it does is for integer, double, and decimal fields. Anyway, for security reasons, client-only validation isn't necessarily a good idea -- a malicious user can still post non-validated data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Asp.net, we do have client side validators like custom validators, regular expression validators etc. Now that web2py does not have them, I wish they could be incorporated in future versions of web2py. And by the way I did not meant client only validator.

Comment: Yes, it would be great to incorporate more client side validation.